# jquery do not submit form until checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Hi I've inserted some jquery in order to validate a checkbox on a certain form, I've made a simple example on my [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pECzh/10/) however the form still submits if the checkbox is not clicked, however the alert is still displayed.

How can i stop the submit taking place if the checkbox is not ticked? My code is below or view my [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pECzh/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var check;

$("#test-with-prop").on("click", function () {
    if ($("input[id=test]").is(":checked")) {
        check = $("#mycheckbox").prop("checked");
        if (!check) {
            alert("Please confirm that you have read and understood the charging agreement between yourself, and .");
        } 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Show the relevant HTML markup within the OP.

Comment: How is this different from your last question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the $.on('submit') as described [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $form = $('#form-id');
    var $checkbox = $('#mycheckbox');

    $form.on('submit', function(e) {
        if(!$checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please confirm!');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/R2jn5/2/).

Comment: Did you test it yourself? I keep getting 'Please confirm' no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

only add the `e.preventDefault();` and cancel the submit:

```
 // Example 3 - With jQuery prop  
    $("#test-with-prop").on("click", function (e) {
        if ($("input[id=test]").is(":checked")) {
            check = $("#mycheckbox").prop("checked");
            if (!check) {
                alert("Please confirm");
                e.preventDefault(); // add this line
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: or `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: better use `e.preventDefault();`, `return false;` will also call `e.stopPropagation();`, although it may suit this case but it's a good practice to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test-with-prop').click(function () {
            if ($('#mycheckbox').is(":checked")) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Checkbox is not selected");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. And use a as Inputtype a Button instead of type="submit"....

```
$("#test-with-prop").on("click", function () {
        if ($("input[id=test]").is(":checked")) {
            check = $("#mycheckbox").prop("checked");
            if (!check) {
                alert("Please confirm that you have read and understood the charging agreement between ");
            } else{
                $("#form").submit();
            }
        }
    });
```